# Form Select Storing ID instead of NAME

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, select, model

Im trying to store the selected value(name) which was retrieved from mysql but it storing the id instead of name? any suggestion?

Views

```php
{{ Form::select('dept',$departments->pluck('name'),null, ['class' => 'form-control','required','placeholder'=>'Select Department']) }}
```

Route

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $departments=Department::pluck('name','id');
    return view('index',compact('departments'));
});
```

Controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
            'staffId' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'dept' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);
        $departments=Department::pluck('name','id');
        $departments->name = $request ->input('dept');
        $user = User::create(request(['fname','lname','staffId','email','dept','role','password']));

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/home2');
    }
```

Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['name'];
    protected $table='department';

}
```

Comment: You are supposed to store the ids, not the actual values. Remember, mysql is a relational database management system. When you query the stored values, use a join to get the names belonging to the ids.

Comment: ...unless you mean it's storing the key instead of the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue

```
<select class="form-control" id="dept" name='dept'>
@if($departments->count() > 0)
@foreach ($departments as $department)
<option value="{{ $department->id }}">{{$department->name}}</option>
@endforeach
@else
No Record Found
@endif  
</select>
```

Dropdown
https://ibb.co/bvR6rc4

Mysql
https://ibb.co/5FG2gWW